# adding a costant manually cause MissingDataError

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, statsmodels

i'm trying to train a linear regression model with a intercept using `statsmodels.api` library (because with this i can get a summary with parameters sgnificance) .

Unfortunately this method does not work

```
X_train_2 = sm.add_constant(X_train)
```

So i try to add manually a 1 costant vector to my X_train  dataset by doing this:

```
const = pd.Series([1]*1460, name='const')


X_train_2 = pd.concat([const , X_train  ] , axis=1)

model_sm_1 = sm.OLS(Y_train , X_train_2  ).fit()
```

but again a get an error:

> File "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 133, in _handle_constant
>       raise MissingDataError('exog contains inf or nans')

MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans

My question are 2:

1) how can i fix this error
2) does exist another library for linear regression that give a summary table? (sklearn doesn't give me this)

Comment: The error tells you that you have missing values in your dataframe so try to pass `missing='drop'` in your `sm.OLS` [function](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html).